# Web api different named actions cause Multiple actions error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-routing

I have web api 2 controller actions:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Response<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
    {
        ....(Get all products)
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Response<Product> Get(int id)
    {
        ....(Get product by id)
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Response<IEnumerable<Product>> Category(int id)
    {
        .... (Get products by category)
    }
```

I want to use this controllers with url:

```
http://localhost/api/product 

http://localhost/api/product/1

http://localhost/api/product/category/1
```

But this url `http://localhost/api/product/1` returns error,

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

My config settings are like this:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using attribute routing rather than global routing here. If you remove your global routes and define your routes on a per-action basis you should have no problems. For example, your routes could look like:

```
[Route("api/product")]
[Route("api/product/{id:int}")]
[Route("api/product/category/{id:int}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two `Get` methods match the same route. I would delete the first `Get` method and change your second `Get` method to use an optional id parameter like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public Response<IEnumerable<Product>> Get(int? id)
{
    // Get all products if id is null, else get product by id and return as a list with one element
}
```

This way, `Get` will match routes for both "product" and "product/1".

Answer (score 0):

This is the default controller created when you create a new ASP.NET Web APi within Visual Studio:

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

And the WebApi config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```